# How to read numeric and string data in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have a large data set which consists of more than 200,000 rows and 43 columns.There are both numeric fields and string fields.I need to read this data set using matlab. I tried using "textscan" but it's not applicable to the whole data set since there's a string field which contains an address where the format is different for each client.(address contains numbers and text).I need only the numeric fields for my analysis.
Is there any function to do this?
Thanks.

Comment: How is the data delimited? Is it an Excel spreadsheet? CSV file?

Answer (score 1):

Try the [interactive import tool](http://www.mathworks.com/videos/importing-data-from-text-files-interactively-71076.html) or the new [readtable](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/readtable.html) function.  The `table` data type is [new in R2013b](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2013/09/10/introduction-to-the-new-matlab-data-types-in-r2013b/).

There are a number of other ways to read text data, summarized nicely on [this MathWorks page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/ways-to-import-text-files.html).  For mixed text/numeric data, your options are limited to `textscan` and `readtable`, but you can also use the interactive tool, `uiimport`. But let's not forget the lower level options using `fread`/`fgetl` and `fscanf` if you really want to get down and dirty.

Comment: The data is delimited using '|'.It's a .txt (text) file.I'm using R2009a version.